# Flutter listview: when removing an Item, the next one inherits some properties

Tags: android, ios, listview, flutter, flutter-layout

I'm working on a proyect where I have a ListView of custom widgets named AlarmCard, each of them is populated with the information of an Alarm object.
An AlarmCard has two boolean propierties: Expanded and Loading, and this is the main code:

```
class _AlarmCardState extends State<AlarmCard>{
  bool _expanded = false;
  bool _loading = false;
  static const double iconSize = 28.0;
  static const Color iconColor = Colors.black87;
  static const TextStyle fieldTextStyle = TextStyle(
    fontSize: 16.0,
    fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
    color: Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 0.6),
  );

  static const TextStyle clearFieldTextStyle = TextStyle(
    fontSize: 16.0,
    fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
    color: Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 0.2),
  );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    TextStyle timeTextStyle = TextStyle(
      fontSize: 54.0,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
      color: Colors.black54,
    );

    Widget card = Card(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Opacity(
            opacity: _loading ? 1.0 : 0.0,
            child: Container(
              height: 3.0,
              child: ClipRRect(
                child: LinearProgressIndicator(),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                  topRight: Radius.circular(3.0),
                  topLeft: Radius.circular(3.0),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(12.0, 8.0, 12.0, 8.0),
            child: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                Row(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 6.0, bottom: 8.0),
                      child: InkWell(
                          onTap: () => _selectTime(context),
                          child: Text(widget.alarm.timeString, style: timeTextStyle)
                      ),
                    ),
                    Switch(value: widget.alarm.enabled, onChanged: _onAlarmEnabledChange),
                  ],
                ),
                AnimatedCrossFade(
                  firstChild: _getContractedBottom(),
                  secondChild: _getExpandedBottom(),
                  duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),
                  crossFadeState: _expanded ? CrossFadeState.showSecond : CrossFadeState.showFirst,
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );

    return _loading ?
      Opacity(
        opacity: 0.6,
        child: IgnorePointer(
          child: card
        ),
      )
      : card;
      }
...
}
```

Of course, there are some more custom widgets as DayToggle and methods as _getContractedBottom() and _getExpandedBottom() which returns a widget.
Once we have defined the AlarmCard build method, which depends on _expanded and _loading, we build the ListView using `final List<Alarm> alarmList` as:

```
ListView.builder(
  itemCount: alarmList.length,
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int i) {
    Alarm alarm = alarmList[i];
    return AlarmCard(
      alarm: alarm,
      ringtones: ringtoneList,
      onAlarmUpdated: () => true,
      onAlarmDeleted: () {
        setState(() {
          alarmList.remove(alarm);
        });
        return true;
      }
    );
  },
)
```

So, the ListView works perfectly, and each item is shown as it should, it can be expanded and updated (so that _loading turns true). The problem comes when an item is deleted.

Imagine alarmList has 8 items, all of them are shown on the screen, and we expand and delete just the 6th item. The moment we press Delete, the AlarmCard turns to Loading state, and then is deleted, but once it's removed from the ListView, the 7th item 'inherits' the _expanded and _loading propierties, so it is shows the right information which corresponds to it's alarm, but it's expanded and loading, while it shouldn't.

Does somebody know where the problem could be?
I've been searching on multiple websites and stackoverflow posts but couldn't find this problem.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: try setState(() {
      list = List.from(list)
        ..removeAt(index);
    });

Comment: @Vineet no, i have just tried it and i get the same error

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I've just run into the exact same issue and was about to ask a question when this popped up

Comment: If I'm not wrong, I think the way I used to fix it was using a UniqueKey in each ListItem. You can get more info about that here https://youtu.be/kn0EOS-ZiIc

Answer (score 1):

as @javired98 said, the problem is in key. that video help me. but remember if you have list of your widget, the key must pass to widget when you add it to your list not define in widget class.

```
          imageList.add(ImageElement(
            key:ValueKey(imageCounter),
            id: ...,
            imgURL: ...,
              .
              .
              . 
           ));
```

Comment: video address :  youtu.be/kn0EOS-ZiIc